# Testdroid for security testing

Tags: testdroid

As part of finalizing a security testing tool for our android app, I was validating various tools and stumbled upon [this](http://testdroid.com/news/testdroid-brings-security-and-vulnerability-testing-for-android-developers) blog. Under How to access this service? Section, step 5 says: Upload your APK and check “Execute security tests”. But I couldn’t find this checkbox. Is it that this will only be available for paid users?

Comment: Seems [Off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for SO, perhaps get in touch with the testdroid support / forum (if any). Blogs can very quickly get outdated.

Comment: I have already sent an email to their support team and waiting for them to reply.

Comment: Testdroid dropped integration with codenomicon